# How to input n lines in a string array?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I have to input an int n, and read n lines in a string array. But when I test my code, for example, I put 3, it will read only 2. I found that I should use vectors, but why, is there any way easier than vectors to read n lines ?

Example code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int n;
    cin >> n;
    string niz[n];

    for (int t1 = 0; t1 < n; t1++) {
        getline(cin, niz[t1]); }

    for (int t2 = 0; t2 < n; t2++) {
        cout << niz[t2] << endl; }
}
```

Comment: As mentioned [recently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30833225/are-arrays-not-dynamically-allocated-in-c) in this queue, VLA's arent a standard feature. Also elaborate about _"and the third will be false."_ please. Your code should work just fine.

Comment: It doesn't work. I would put this here if it works fine.

Comment: _"It doesn't work"_ Isn't helpfuly for anyone. So some mentions about given [inputs, expected outputs](http://ideone.com/2UTSNf)? Improve your question please.

Comment: I don't know how ideone knew this, because I didn't paste the code. Wow. However, here, check: http://ideone.com/2UTSNf

Comment: I made it knowing about your code of course.

Comment: *"I found that I should use vectors"* Yes, you really should. *"is there any way easier than vectors to read n lines"* No, `std::vector` is the right tool for this job.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that when you read the number of lines the newline is still left in the stream, so the first line that is read is just an empty line (what remains after the number that you input).

See and example exchange of input and output when I modify the program a little to prefix each line of output:

```
C:\so-test>test
3
Mary had
A little lamb.
line [0]:
line [1]: Mary had
line [2]: A little lamb.
```

For the moment, I'll leave the solution as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

In the first for loop, first iteration takes what's left in that row after you input ***n***. You can just put `cin.ignore();` before the first for loop to ignore the rest of that line. It should work now.